# Verify FIT image signature in Linux userspace

Tags: u-boot

I'm working on software update for my device. The image is a FIT image with RSA signature. My u-boot can verify it before booting it.

I'm wondering if there's a tool in linux userspace to do the same verification. Basically, my device running Linux downloads a FIT image, verifies it before writing it to flash. The verification step is what I don't have.

I guess I can sign the whole FIT image, but it's kind of a waste since my FIT already has RSA signature in it.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more details on your machine, OS/custom distro, the signature (an embedded file?) so it would be easier to help you out and be useful for future readers?

Comment: Paradox. My device runs custom Linux built with buildroot. The bootloader is u-boot. The FIT (flatten device tree) image is a way to package stuff (kernel, dtb...) to be booted by u-boot. U-boot provides tools to help build FIT images with optional RSA signature. Uboot verifies the signature automatically at bootup. I'm just wondering if there's a tool in Linux that does the same verification.

Comment: Yes, but if the FIT image is not embedded on your device in the same state you built it, I am not aware of a way of checking the signature of a running custom Linux image already altered by booting (it's the bootloader job AFAIK). I will let someone who might know better about it to try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I need to be clear. I'm working on system update. Basically, the device running Linux downloads the FIT image, verifies it before writing it to flash. The verification step is what I'm missing right now.

Comment: This can done. Could you all of these details in your question, please?

Comment: Do you have the signature generated let's from `mkimage`?

Comment: The signature is embedded in the FIT image, whose format I'm not clear about. I'm reading uboot source to figure out the details.

Comment: Could you provide your building process so we can help you out? E.g. if you are using `mkimage` when cross-compiling, you will have the signature of your image and therefore be able to check its signature later on.

Comment: I think I have an answer. I just posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer. U-Boot has a tool called "fit_check_sign".

If you use buildroot, these are the broad strokes:

- include package "uboot-tools" for your target.
- Enable FIT and FIT_SIGNATURE options for the package.
- build the system.
- in ..../output/build/uboot-tools-*/tools, there's "fit_check_sign". Copy that to target. You can do that in post-build script.
- From target, run the following to verify:

  ```
   ./fit_check_sign -f your_fit_image -k uboot_dtb_file_containing_public_key
  ```